# Ruby 'sub!' doesn't replace text if/elsif statements

Tags: ruby, string, replace, gsub

This has been driving me crazy for far longer than it should, I'm using SIMPLE string replacement, and yet it fails to replace the string (in which case, it is 'url') according to the information it gets.

```
class Test
  myURL = 'www.google.com'
puts 'Where are you from?'
  location = gets
    if location == 'England'
     myURL['.com'] = '.co.uk'
    elsif location == 'France'
     myURL['.com'] = '.co.fr'
    end
puts myURL
end
```

Am I going crazy?

Comment: You're not using `sub!` in your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `location = gets` to `location = gets.chomp`

What is happening with `gets` is it is picking up everything you type into the prompt which includes the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. So, if you type in "England" then:

```
location == "England\n" #=> true
location == "England"   #=> false
```

The [`String#chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) method will remove the terminating line at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to do:

```
class Test
    myURL = 'www.google.com'
    puts 'Where are you from?'
    location = gets.chomp
    if location == 'England'
        myURL['.com'] = '.co.uk'
    elsif location == 'France'
        myURL['.com'] = '.co.fr'
    end
    puts myURL
end
```

The reason is that the string returned by `gets` has a linebreak at the end.